# Inverse function of a set larger than original set

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm trying to work on my proof writing ability and tried to prove the following theorem. 
let$ \: f:A\rightarrow B \; ,\:  C\subseteq A$ Prove $C\subseteq f^{-1}[f(C)]$

let $x\in C$ so $\: f(x)\in B$
note that $f(C)\subseteq B$ now there are two cases to consider: $f^{-1}$ is a function or not. Now if $f^{-1}[f(C)]$ is a function, in which case $C=f^{-1}[f(C)]$ then $C\subseteq f^{-1}[f(C)]$. 
If $f^{-1}$ is not a function then there exists elements in $f(C)$ such that $f^{-1}[f(C)]= b_{1}$ and  $ b_{2}$ where $ b_{1}$ may or may not be and element of $C$ and sim. for $ b_{2}$. In any case, we have 2 elements instead of 1 and therefore $C\subseteq f^{-1}[f(C)]$

The things that I am concerned about is that in the proof I didnt really use the $x\in C$ assumption to lead to $f(C)\subseteq B$, I dont really know how to do this, but Im fairly certain I cant just begin the proof with this as an assumption. Also in my second case I dont think I set up the equality correctly for $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The breaking into the cases where $f^{-1}$ is a function and not a function is not correct in my opinion, since in this context $f^{-1}$ is meant to be the inverse image of a set. They're different even in the case that $f^{-1}$ exists (slightly, this may be just be dogma on my end).

Also, choosing the two elements thing ($b_1, b_2$) didn't really make too much sense to me.
Here's an idea:
Suppose $x\in C$. Then $f(x)\in f(C)$. But by definition, the inverse image of any set $Y$ is $f^{-1}(Y)=\{w: f(w)\in Y\}$. So this implies $x\in f^{-1}(f(C))$. So $C\subset f^{-1}(f(C))$.

It's really best to work straight from definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, chose the 2 element thing by negating definition of a function.

Comment: Oh I see. You could do something like that, but for something like this it really is preferable to do it exactly from definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $c\in C$. Then $f(c)\in f(C)$ and so $c\in f^{-1}(f(C))$. Thus $C\subseteq f^{-1}(f(C))$